# How To Remove the black background in div css

Tags: html, css

I'm new in web development and I have a small problem with my code, I want to remove the black background around the word "logo" in - div -

***HTML***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
<title>NoThing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Testcss.css">
</head>


<body>
<header class="myheader">
   <div><h1>Logo</h1></div>
</header>
</body>
```

***CSS***

```
       * {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: black;
}
.myheader {
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0 ;
    display: flex;
    transition: 0.6s;
}
h1 {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

thanks

Comment: try to remove `background-color: black;` from `*` selector

Comment: Waseem Almoliky thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is this line of code

```
  * {
    **background-color: black;**
}
```

When you're writting css code, the * means that you are going to apply the attributes you write there and you can't change them ( as far as i know ), and actually it's a bad practice doing that if you want to apply styles to all items, if you want all items to have black color by default, you can use another tag, like..

```
html{
background-color: black;
}
```

it's the same as * but now if you want to change the color of an specific div, it will work !

And by the way, i wish you the best through your coding journey, this is an amazing world, hope you can learn a lot !